# IIS 6 - sort websites by name

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

In IIS 6 on a Server 2003 box, when I view the list of websites, it doesn't list them in alphabetical order.  I'm assuming that it sorts them on their website ID.

I have one server that won't be getting upgraded to 2008 for a while and it hosts about 40 websites.  It has become quite cumbersome for me to look through the list to find the website that I need to modify.  Is there any possible way to sort these websites alphabetically based on their website name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the treeview items ? You can't to the best of my knowledge.
If you mean the listview you see when "Web sites" is selected in the treeview you can click the listview header columns to sort them variously.

If you don't see any columns hit View > Add Remove Columns and make sure all the columns are displayed.

[alt text http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/4623/iissortpl0.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/4623/iissortpl0.png)

Comment: Don't I feel stupid.  I was always looking at the treeview. I don't know why I didn't just think to click the node above it and sort there.

Makes me feel as dumb as the fact that Microsoft didn't sort the treeview by the website name.

Thanks.

Comment: No worries, i've cursed many a times at the crooked treeview sorting such a pain!